# Not able to run rake and bundle

Tags: ruby, rvm, rbenv

I just moved from rvm to rbenv. When I see gem env I get the followings.

```
RubyGems Environment:
- RUBYGEMS VERSION: 2.0.3
  - RUBY VERSION: 1.9.3 (2012-11-10 patchlevel 327) [x86_64-darwin12.4.0]
  - INSTALLATION DIRECTORY: /Users/teacher/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327
  - RUBY EXECUTABLE: /Users/teacher/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p327/bin/ruby
  - EXECUTABLE DIRECTORY: /Users/teacher/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327/bin
  - RUBYGEMS PLATFORMS:
    - ruby
    - x86_64-darwin-12
  - GEM PATHS:
     - /Users/teacher/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327
     - /Users/teacher/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327@global
     - /usr/local/Cellar/rbenv-gem-rehash/1.0.0
  - GEM CONFIGURATION:
     - :update_sources => true
     - :verbose => true
     - :backtrace => false
     - :bulk_threshold => 1000
  - REMOTE SOURCES:
     - https://rubygems.org/
```

Even though I used rvm implode, I still have installation and executable directory in .rvm. I think the dir is created when I run gem install bundler.

I don't think it is right, but I don't know what to do.

Now when I install gem install bundler, it is installed in .rvm file and I am not able to run bundle install after installing gem install bundler.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you close and reopen your terminal window or try opening a new one?

You might have environment variables still pointing to RVM. What happens when you run `rvm info`? Are the RVM initializations still in your ~/.bash_profile or ~/.bashrc files?

Answer (score 0):

Adding to the Tin Man's answer, I did the followings as well. I googled it but there is no post regarding the details for noobs. I hope this will help some in future.

- I have to dig all my .bash_profile, .bashrc, .profile top of .my zshrc and deleted anything to do with rvm.

I added the followings to my .zshrc.(or your terminal file, e.g. .bash_profile or .bashrc or .profile)

```
############
# Ruby rbenv
############
export PATH="$HOME/.rbenv/bin:$PATH"
eval "$(rbenv init -)"
# required for https://github.com/imathis/octopress/issues/144
export LC_CTYPE=en_US.UTF-8
export LANG=en_US.UTF-8
```

I also deleted /Users/teacher/pear/bin which is used for phpunit. (I will figure it out later.)

- As the Tin Man suggested I quit my iTerm and restarted.
- I read [this post](http://www.reinteractive.net/posts/12-moving-from-rvm-to-rbenv) and followed the instruction. I even reinstalled rail as in the post. This installed basic gems.
- I have to uninstall rake-0.9.2.2 and installed rake-0.9.6

e.g.

```
bundle exec gem uninstall rake-0.9.2.2
sudo bundle install
bundle show rake # check the version
```

Since I was on the way to installing a new template, I followed [this post](http://www.viggiosoft.com/blog/blog/2011/09/28/setting-up-a-blog-with-octopress/).

```
rake install["theme-name"]
bundle install                # Keep gems updated
rake update_source            # update the template's source
rake update_style             # update the template's style
```